# Create new array only to print checked rows from table

Tags: php

I have a table populated by a query, through a simple foreach loop. Now, I want to print the checked rows of that table, but the table that is currently printable it's on a another `<div>`, because they got completely different formats and styles and the second table(the one that actually I am able to print) gets the data with the exact same query as a result_array.

I am trying to figure out how to convert the first table's checked rows into a separate array and use that one instead of the query of the second one, so only the checked rows can be print.

I have been trying to print the 1st table itself but it doesn't show as I want and it uses a lot of color ink (which is out of question).
I have been trying different ways for quite some time now, but I didn't realize that they were on different containers(totally a dumb mistake, ik) and it just hit the idea of making this new array to make it happen, but just have no idea how to proceed.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="TLL">
<table class="table table-bordered" style="color: Black" id="table-3">
<?php
$control_info= $this->db->query("select * 
                                from controlsemanal 
                                where vendedora = 'Taller' 
                                and Indicador != '1' 
                                and Indicador !='100' 
                                ORDER BY FIELD (Id_Status,1,3,4,5,6,2,7,0) ");
?>
<thead> etc etc </thead>

<tbody>
<?php
$arr_loop = $control_info;
foreach ($arr_loop->result_array() as $row) {
<tr> <th>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="">
</div>
</th>
etc etc
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and this is the printable table

```
<div style="display:none" id="imprimeme3">
$control_info= $this->db->query("select * 
                                from controlsemanal 
                                where vendedora = 'Taller' 
                                and Indicador != '1' 
                                and Indicador !='100' 
                                ORDER BY FIELD (Id_Status,1,3,4,5,6,2,7,0) ");
<table>
foreach ($control_info->result_array() as $row) {
etc etc
}
</table>

<center>
<button style="border:0;background:#04998A;color:white;width:550px;height:50px;font-size: 30px" onclick="imprimir3();">
<b>IMPRIMIR</b>
</button>
</center>
</div>
```

the function to print the 2nd table

```
function imprimir3() {
        var objeto = document.getElementById('imprimeme3'); 
        var ventana = window.open('', '_blank'); 
        ventana.document.write(objeto.innerHTML);        
        ventana.document.close();
        ventana.print();
        ventana.close();
    }
```

I tried to make the code as short as possible here to not be a bother, any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have a form? How do you store checked items? Or, do you want the user to check only items and print them using javascript with no form processing?

Comment: yes, i was trying it without the form, but now i dont know if its posible. not gonna lie, i am sort of new in php/javascript.

Comment: Yes, is possible, bellow the table add the button to print and select just the rows with the marked checkbox. I'll try it later.

Comment: how do i select them? with the `if(isset($_post[check]))` ? just like that?

Comment: Do you have an ID column or unique index in the table?

Comment: ah yes, i got "reference" as the primary key on the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, creating the form in the first piece of code, use your primary key as the value for checkboxes:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="TLL">
<table class="table table-bordered" style="color: Black" id="table-3">
<?php
$control_info= $this->db->query("select * 
                                from controlsemanal 
                                where vendedora = 'Taller' 
                                and Indicador != '1' 
                                and Indicador !='100' 
                                ORDER BY FIELD (Id_Status,1,3,4,5,6,2,7,0) ");
?>
<thead> etc etc </thead>

<tbody>
<?php
$arr_loop = $control_info;
foreach ($arr_loop->result_array() as $row) {
?>
<tr> <th>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $row['referencia']; ?>">
</div>
</th>
etc etc
</tr>
<?php
} // I guess foreach ends here
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Then in your second table (process $_POST form) get only marked items:

1. `check` must be an array, containing `reference` for each marked item
2. Unmarked checkboxes are not sent with form
3. Make a list from them to create the filter "ref1, ref2, ... refX"

I'm guessing your reference column is numeric, if don't, comment and I'll fix the query

```
$referencias = (isset($_POST['check'])) ? implode(', ', $_POST['check']) : '';

// Create your query, filtering by $references
$control_info= $this->db->query("select * 
                            from controlsemanal 
                            where vendedora = 'Taller'
                            and referencia IN ($referencias)
                            ORDER BY FIELD (Id_Status,1,3,4,5,6,2,7,0) ");
// Create your table here
```

Comment: well, now this is embarrassing, thw whole table disappeared, i wrote it like this
<form>
<table>
foreach{
checkbox }
</table>
</form>
wast that right?

Comment: Wich table, the first one? Do you see an error message?

Comment: no error message, yeah the first one, the second one does not diplay on screen, but even the buttom is gone. i tried with just 'form' and fith 'form id="tab" method="post" but didnt work'. PD: this tables were on a nav-tab table, but i erease all other tables to see if it shows... it didnt help, and all the other tables are completly independent to each other so the changes shouldnt have been an issue.

Comment: ok, i fix the issue with the table, now its visible. the button on the other hand is still yet to appear...

Comment: The second form should be visible after processing the form via post, otherwise we should find the way to do that with only javascript.

Comment: i gotta go now, i going to research about it. its okay if i keep asking u later?

Comment: Yeah, it's ok. See you later.

Comment: HELLO AGAIN, i moved the bottom to the top of the table and shows just fine, the promblem now is  here "  Referencia IN ($Referencia) and Indicador != '1'   " it says its a syntax error,  to be clear, $Referencia its the $References u wrote in the code, i just change it to match with the db.

Comment: look, i change the `IN ($referencia)` to `  = ($'referencia' ) ` and now it actually works, but only gives me back the first checked row... any thougts?

Comment: What type of column is referencia?

Comment: its numeric type

Comment: I've updated the answer, changing `reference` to `referencia`. Just be sure the checkboxes name are `check[]`, so you'll receive all marked ones as array. I've also updated the query, to filter only by `referencia`, you don't need any other column to filter.

Comment: ohhh man, it was probably the extra columns in the query cause now its working perfect, thank  so much!